# Swift 2 Converting from String To Number

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following the Stanford Videos for `iOS` development and I am using `Xcode 7` with `Swift 2`. 
I wrote the code from the video line by line, however I keep getting an error.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var userIsTyping = false

@IBAction func AppendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsTyping {
        display.text = display.text! + digit
    } else {
        display.text = digit
        userIsTyping = true
    }
}

var operandStack = Array<Double>()

@IBAction func enter() {
    userIsTyping = false
    operandStack.append(displayValue)
}

var displayValue: Double {
    get{
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set (newValue){
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsTyping = false

    }
}


}
```

At the line where I return

`NumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue`

I get an error of

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: Your label `display` is nil or contains not-number-string.

Answer (score 1):

A conversion can fail. The result can be nil. The "!" means "compiler, I am 100 percent sure that the result can never be nil, so if it is ever nil then please crash". Guess what, sometimes it is nil.

Use "if let".

PS. I think it is very, very unhealthy to take user interface elements (like the title of a button) and to assume they have certain values.

Comment: Indeed. There is this thing called "user input sanitation/validation".

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off substituting that return statement with a much simpler:

```
return Double(display.text!)!
```

Answer (score 0):

let Number = (NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(xtxt.text!)as! Double)

```
 return Number
```